# Use integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to evaluate integrals using substitution. I had

$$\int (x+1)(3x+1)^9 dx$$

My solution: Let $u=3x+1$ then $du/dx=3$

$$u=3x+1 \implies 3x=u-1 \implies x=\frac{1}{3}(u-1) \implies x+1=\frac{1}{3}(u+2) $$

Now I get $$\frac{1}{3} \int (x+1)(3x+1)^9 (3 \,dx) = \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{3}(u+2)u^9 du = \frac{1}{9} \int (u+2)u^9 du \\
= \frac{1}{9} \int (u^{10}+2u^9)\,du = \frac{1}{9}\left( \frac{u^{11}}{11}+\frac{2u^{10}}{10} \right) + C$$

But then I get to this one

$$\int (x^2+2)(x-1)^7 dx$$

and the $x^2$ in brackets is throwing me off.

I put $u=x-1\implies x=u+1,$ hence $x^2+2 =(u+1)^2 +2 = u^2+3$. So
$$ \int(x^2+2)(x-1)^7\, dx = \int (u+1)u^7 du = \int (u+u^7) du = \frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^8}{8} + C $$
Is this correct or have I completely missed the point?

Comment: I did not read the first. There is an algebra slip in the second. We have $x^2+2=u^2+2u+3$, so you will be integrating $u^9+2u^8+3u^7$. I think you basically have the point, just made a mistake. Well, more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice work, (though a wee bit hard to read).

Let's look a bit more closely at the second integral.

Your substitution is correct: $$u = x-1 \implies x = u+1,\;dx = du, \\ x^2 + 2 =(u+1)^2 + 2$$

You got a bit mixed up when substituting into the factor $x^2 + 2$, to express it as a function of $u$.

Substituting, we get  $$\begin{align}\int (x^2 + 2)(x-1)^7\,dx & = \int ((u+1)^2 + 2)u^7\,du \\ \\
&= \int(u^2 + 2u + 3)u^7\,du \\ \\ 
&= \int(u^9 + 2u^8+ 3u^7)\,du\end{align}$$

I trust you can take it from here.

Comment: Ah right I see where I went wrong. That was a great help thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, skeeto!

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was about integration by substitution, but if you want another way, you can also do it using [tabular integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts)

$$x^2 + 2 \quad \quad \quad (x-1)^7$$

$$2x \quad \quad \quad \frac 1 8 (x-1)^8$$

$$2 \quad \quad \quad \frac 1 {72} (x-1)^9$$

$$0 \quad \quad \quad \frac 1 {720} (x-1)^{10}$$

So you get

$$(x^2 + 2)\left({\frac 1 8}\right)(x-1)^8 - (2x)\left({\frac 1 {72}}\right)(x-1)^9 + (2)\left({\frac 1 {720}}\right)(x-1)^{10} + C$$

If anyone can make the LaTeX look cool with arrows or an actual table I'd be much obliged :)

Answer (score -3):

$\frac{19683 x^{11}}{11}+\frac{39366 x^{10}}{5}+15309 x^9+17496 x^8+13122 x^7+6804 x^6+\frac{12474 x^5}{5}+648 x^4+117 x^3+14 x^2+x$